# Проблема с функцией определения типа узла в дереве

Tags: c++, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Нужно дать переменной одно из трех значений: `К, П, Л`. В зависимости от того, где располагается вершина в дереве. Я написал две функции: `Tnode_type2(Tnode*&, int)` ищет промежуточный узел и лист, вторая - `Tnode_type(Tnode*&, int)` ищет корень, но в первой вторая часть условия вообще игнорируется, не понимаю как найти лист в дереве. Делал все и в одной функции, но там та же проблема была. Помогите с алгоритмом нахождения листа в дереве.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    struct Tnode {
      int x;
      Tnode *right;
      Tnode *left;
    };

    void add_node(int x, Tnode *&Tree) {
        if (NULL == Tree) {
           Tree = new Tnode;
           Tree->x = x;
           Tree->left = NULL;
           Tree->right = NULL;
           return;
        }
        if (x > Tree->x)
          add_node(x, Tree->right);
        else
          add_node(x, Tree->left);
    }

    void print(Tnode *t) {
     if (t == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        print(t->left);
        cout << t->x << endl;
        print(t->right);
    }
}

void del(Tnode *&Tree) {
    if (Tree != NULL) {
        del(Tree->left);
        del(Tree->right);
        delete Tree;
        Tree = NULL;
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
char Tnode_type2(Tnode *&Tree, int v) {
    if (Tree->x == v && Tree->left || Tree->right) 
        return 'П';
    if (Tree->x == v && !Tree->left && !Tree->right)
        return 'Л';
    Tnode_type2( (Tree->x > v ? Tree->right :Tree->left), v);
}
char Tnode_type(Tnode *&Tree, int v) {
    if (Tree->x == v) 
        return 'К';
    else return Tnode_type2(Tree, v);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    Tnode *Tree = NULL;
    char b = ' ';
    int x = 0, n = 0, ver = 0;
    cout << "Введите кол-во эл-ов дерева:\t";
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Введите эллемент:\t";
        cin >> x;
        add_node(x, Tree);
    }

    cout << "\nВаше дерево:\n";
    print(Tree);

    cout << "\nВведите значение вершины:\t";
    cin >> ver;

    b = Tnode_type(Tree, ver);
    cout << "\nОтвет:\t" << b << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А Вы ver вводите точно такой, который имеется в дереве? Потому что особенность условий && в if в том, что если первое не выполнено, то другие игнорируются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char Tnode_type2(Tnode *&Tree, int v)
{
    if (Tree->x == v && Tree->left || Tree->right) 
        return 'П';
    if (Tree->x == v && !Tree->left && !Tree->right)
        return 'Л';
    return Tnode_type2( (Tree->x > v ? Tree->right :Tree->left), v);
}
```

Надо добавить `return` инструкцию. Далее это:

```
if (Tree->x == v && Tree->left || Tree->right)
```

Надо бы добавить скобки для промежуточного так:

```
if (Tree->x == v && (Tree->left || Tree->right))
```

Comment: После всех исправлений в условии первого if та же ошибка - Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x003324A3 в AlgLab3_Tan.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000.

Comment: @Maksim_Ohotnikov данная ошибка возникает, если Вы передаете в эту функцию нулевой указатель на Tnode. Далее возникает попытка розыменования Tree->x и происходит упомянутая ошибка. Ошибку легко воспроизвести, если создать «дерево» из одного узла со значением x = a и ввести для поиска ver != a. Проследите вызовы и найдите точку возникновения сами. Ваша проблема решается введением проверок принимаемых или пересылаемых указателей на нулевость. Рекомендую посмотреть ресурсы по технике написания безопасного кода.

Comment: спасибо за скобки, не заметил глупой ошибки. Ошибка с исключением по адресу из-за неправильного условия тернарной операции.
    `return Tnode_type2( (Tree->x < v ? Tree->right :Tree->left), v);`